# command 'expo' not found - in the terminal

Tags: error-handling

I am putting this code ' expo init name app' and it's not working.
The erros says 'zsh: command not found: expo '

I tried the code 'expo init app name'

Comment: To use the `expo` command you have to install the `expo-cli` package (see https://docs.expo.dev/archive/expo-cli/). However, it is deprecated now. See https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/ for the current state of the art.